# Required Field Not work in Safari Browser

Tags: html, browser

I have tried following code for make the required field to notify the required field but its not working in safari browser.
Code:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
        <input  required />Your name:
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Above the code work in firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/X8UXQ/179/

Thanks

Comment: looks like question for stackoverflow ?

Comment: Rung that code in safari browser. it will not work

Comment: This site is dedicated to salesforce related technologies, you'll have better luck posting on stackoverflow.com which handles all programing languages and has much more htlm experts.

Answer (score 2):

Newer browser features are typically not supported everywhere and this is an example. Check sites like [http://caniuse.com//#search=required](http://caniuse.com/#search=required) if you are in any doubt.

You then have to decide what fallback to use where the feature is not supported or decide to avoid the feature altogether.

Comment: Cant we achieve?

Comment: Not just by adding "required".

Comment: So how to achieve?

Comment: @rakish Google for polyfills for this feature e.g. http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/polyfills-for-form-validation/. Or if you use Visualforce it has its own required mechanisms.